# Do I need to purchase a mysql commercial license if I'm running a LAMP based website?

Tags: mysql, web-hosting, licensing

Does it make a difference if I'm selling products on the website rather than just hosting content like a blog?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can use the Community Server edition of MySQL free of charge for any use.

Only if you require the additional tools of the Enterprise Server edition do you need to license. We use the Community Server edition for many commercial websites and are quite happy with it.